# HTTP Get Angular 1.5 component

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use a 1.5 component with AngularJS. I have a service that gets my JSON file using $HTTP and returns the promise. I then resolve the promise in my components controller and assign it to a value on the controller using `this.work`. Although this doesn't show in my HTML page. I have included comments in the code to explain a little better if this is confusing.

It's my understanding that the resolving of the promise (in my controller) is happening asynchronously but once it's resolved why am I not shown the updated changed to the variable `$ctrl.work` in the view. Instead I never get a value from the variable.

```
    // Component
    (function () {
        angular.module('development')
            .component('pgDev', {
                templateUrl: 'app/development/development.template.html',
                controller: ['workList', function (workList) {

                    //this.work = 'HELLO WORLD'; // <- this shows up in the html if uncommented

                    workList.getWorkItems().then(function (d) {
                        console.log(d.test); // outputs: myjsonfile
                        this.work = d.test; // <- this doesnt show in the html
                    });

                }]
            })
    }());

    // HTTP Get Service
    (function () {
        angular.module("development").factory("workList", ["$http",
            function ($http) {
                return {
                    getWorkItems: function () {
                        return $http.get("data/worklist/worklist.json").then(function (d) {
                            return d.data;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }])
    })();

    // html
    workitems: {{$ctrl.work}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loosing context of execution which means that `this` inside your callback function if not and instance of component controller. A simple (and modern) solution is to use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of normal anonymous:

```
workList.getWorkItems().then(d => {
    this.work = d.test;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. If you know, or could point me in the right direction, using `this` to assign things within the controller seems problematic in the sense that I could never assign something to the controller using `this` inside a function since, as you stated in your answer, the context of this would not be related to the controller component. So what way should things be done (rather than using arrow functions)?

Comment: You can save reference to correct `this` in the beginning and use it later: `const self = this; ... self.work = d.test`. But this is old school. Arrow function is the purest solution.